# How do I pass this data i get from axios to the backend which uses node.js (react & node.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

This is the backend (node.js) route that i want to send the data to.

```
app.post('/saveDiseaseDetails' , (req , res) => {
  //Console.log the data here
})
```

This is the axios that returns some data and I want to send that data to the backend

```
axios.post("https://api.plant.id/v2/identify", data)
  .then(({ data }) => console.log("SUCCESS", data))}
```

Basically, what I want is to get the data from the axios request and console.log it in the backend. I am new to react and axios so I am having a little bit trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frontend

```
const url_to_your_backend //this has to be added accordingly
axios.post("https://api.plant.id/v2/identify", data)
  .then(async({ data }) =>{
       console.log("SUCCESS", data)
       const backend_response=await axios.post(url_to_your_backend,data,{})
       console.log("backend response",backend_response)
   })
```

Backend

```
app.post('/saveDiseaseDetails' , (req , res) => {
  //Console.log the data here
  console.log(req.body)
  res.status(200).json({message:"received data in backend})
})
```